# GKE Config Connector asking for resource.type which does not seem to be mandatory

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-config-connector

I've got this config connector resource set up for alerting policy

```
apiVersion: monitoring.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: MonitoringAlertPolicy
metadata:
  name: testing-bff-alert
  namespace: config-connector
spec:
  alertStrategy:
    autoClose: 604800s
  combiner: OR
  conditions:
    - conditionThreshold:
        aggregations:
          - alignmentPeriod: 120s
            crossSeriesReducer: REDUCE_MEAN
            perSeriesAligner: ALIGN_DELTA
        comparison: COMPARISON_GT
        duration: 0s
        filter: metric.type="logging.googleapis.com/user/bff-prod-response-times"
        thresholdValue: 50
        trigger:
          count: 1
      displayName: 'BFF Response Times [Mean]'
  displayName: 'BFF Response Times [Mean] above 0.8s'
  documentation:
    content: BFF Response times are too high
    mimeType: text/markdown
  enabled: true
  notificationChannels:
    - external: "projects/my-project/notificationChannels/17980363"
    - name: slack-notification
      namespace: config-connector
```

The problematic part when applying this, is that the server complains about the filter missing the `resource.type` filter.

```
Update call failed: error applying desired state: summary: Error updating AlertPolicy "my-project projects/my-project/alertPolicies/65948650919": googleapi: Error 400: Field alert_policy.conditions[0].condition_threshold.filter had an invalid value of "metric.type="logging.googleapis.com/user/bff-prod-response-times"": must specify a restriction on "resource.type" in the filter; see "https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources" for a list of available resource types.
```

Now, from the actual metrics UI, I know that specifying *just* the `metric.type` filter works, and that it does not need anything else to work. In the UI adding `AND resource.type="metric"` to the existing (and working) `metric.type` just results in an empty chart with no data. So clearly my choice of `resource.type="metric"` isn't right.

And when I extract the configuration in YAML form from the server using the `gcloud` CLI, that too only has the `metric.type`, and nothing else.

Does anybody have any ideas about why this might be the case and what I can do to fix it? Or what additional `resource.type` filter I could be using that *will* work?
I've been looking at https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#service-names and haven't have had much luck guessing what other `resource.type` I should be using

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to use [conditionMonitoringQueryLanguage](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/monitoring/monitoringalertpolicy#spec) as the condition on your yaml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out that whilst the visual editor allows you to NOT specify the resource type, the configuration approach does require you to use it, and in this case, it's `resource.type="k8s_container"`

The way we figured this out was by looking through all of the resources, and realising that the log based metrics appear in both the "Unspecified" section, as well as the "Kubernetes Container" section...

[image]